# how to design dynamic ui in android like the image below

Tags: android, android-layout, dynamic-ui

i am trying to design dynamic ui layout in android to present the date like the image below. i am **facing the *challenges* in the creating an view as clustered in the below mail **[image: attendance ui]

> i tried using list view!

but the each appeares in diffrent line, **it dose not lookes like the image as below!** is that possible to design like this. if so how to do that?

Comment: check this library https://github.com/vipulasri/Timeline-View

Comment: hi @vishnu vigneshwar i am using you library i ma not getting line only getting markes

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a few custom views, e.g. this circles with dates, this labels on the left and rights with xml layouts. Next, create parent view with some container layout, e.g. `FrameLayout`. In this parent view override it's `onDraw()` method, and there manually create and add every layout. It is simple, but might be not efficent, when there are many of views